# How to prevent an empty input field from being considered wrong when using jquery blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a function that should evaluate whether you inserted the correct answer or not.  However, if you enter the wrong word and then go to the other input field it will evaluate the word you had inserted, if it's wrong it will turn red.  Now comes the problem: you most likely went on to the other input field when the word turns red, this is because it has the `blur` function of jquery.  If you would click on the previous input field to correct your wrong doing it will consider the empty input field you had just clicked on to fill out as a wrong one as well (because of the blur again). I know I have to create something that will evaluate whether the input field is empty or not, if yes: don't evaluate, if yes, evaluate.   From what I tried doing it didn't work. This is what I have right now:

```
            var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control syl-input',
            'name':  +c++,
            'id': +idsyll++
        }).on('blur', function() {
            var cValue = $(this).val();
            if (cValue === syllable) {
              correctSylls.push(cValue);
              console.log(correctSylls);
            }
            if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
                $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').addClass('btn btn-success').removeClass('form-control').prop('disabled', true);
                S.addRight();
                S.playRight();
            } else if (cValue !== syllable){
                $(this).css({'color':'#e00413'});
                S.playWrong();
                S.addWrong();
         }
```

How can I make such an `if` statement and where should it be placed?  The `else if` statement evaluates an empty input field as well.

Comment: `if (cValue === '') return` ?

Comment: No offence, but a lot of your questions are about empty strings. Is the comparison of a variable and `""` unclear for you? `if(someVar == "")` checks if the value of someVar is an empty string. `if(someVar === "")` does the same but also checks if someVar is a of the type string.

Comment: That is very correct Mark, no offence taken haha. Answer: No, I often do know in what direction I should look: Problem however: Javascript and Jquery are something new to me and I try to do it as much as possible with Js and jquery. I often do know what the problem is, how to even say what the problem is, but I never know how to put it down in code language. I tried something similiar just like ur answer but never succeeded. I hope this clarified why a lot of my questions are about empty strings etc. My school is kind of garbage in actually TEACHING, so internet is my teacher. :)

Comment: @JJShaw Yeah learning to code can be pretty hard in the start. But it's a lot easier once you got the basics. Good luck with your education.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do to trick.

```
.on('blur', function() {
    var cValue = $(this).val();
    if(cValue === "") {
        return;
    }
    //rest of your code.
});
```